# how to get in R a list or dataframe with the id of the node and its degree

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, igraph

I built a network from a matrix, calculate the degree with degree_gen<-degree(g, mode="all") and when I obtain and save it as an excel I have a column with only the degree and I have not been able to create a dataframe that has the id of the node in a column and in the second column the degree

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try

```
stack(degree_gen)
```

to produce a dataframe with both node ID and degree